# UWP ScrollIntoView in SemanticZoom

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to scroll into view in SemanticZoom? The SemanticZoom has not the ScrollIntoView method (in contrast to ListView). So when the SemanticView is zoomed in, I can't zoom to a group element. I tried to do this by recovering the ScrollViewer like this:

```
var root = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(semanticView, 0);
var scrollviewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, 0) as ScrollViewer;
```

... but I am not able to get the UIElement of the target element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded in recovering my gridview contained in the ZoomedInView. In fact, I was using a CollectionViewSource in this GridView. And it happens that it is also possible to scroll to a group and not just to an item, which I did not know.

Answer (score 1):

To synchronize `ZoomedInView` and `ZoomedOutView` you can use below code

```
private void SemanticZoom_ViewChangeStarted(object sender, SemanticZoomViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsSourceZoomedInView == false)
    {
        e.DestinationItem.Item = e.SourceItem.Item;
    }
}
```

If you want to scroll some other time then use below code

```
var zoomLoc = new SemanticZoomLocation() { Item = /* Item to navigate */};
mySemanticZoom.ZoomedInView.MakeVisible(zoomLoc);
```

Comment: as I mentioned, I have no problem retrieving the scrollviewer. On the other hand I can not scroll up an element from its index. Note, I am trying to do this in a SemanticZoom control which is zoomed in.

Comment: the problem is the SemanticZoom does not contains the ContainerFromIndex method as the ListViewBase. And I can not get it with the SemanticZoom when its IsZoomedInViewActive property value is true.

Comment: @SamuelLIOULT Do you want to synchronize `ZoomedInView` and `ZoomedOutView`?

Comment: Suppose my SemanticView is in the ZoomedInView state. I want to scroll into a target item from its index. But I can't get the corresponding DependencyObject and scroll to it. But when the SemanticZoom is in the ZoomedOutView state, I have no problem because I have a ListView in this view so I can use the ScrollIntoView method. Is that clearer?

Comment: @SamuelLIOULT I understand your problem. My question is, Do you want to go to your "target item" in `ViewChangeStarted` event or some other time?

Comment: I want to do it some other time. But I finally succeeded in recovering my gridview contained in the ZoomedInView. In fact, I was using a collectionviewsource in this gridview. And it happens that it is also possible to scroll to a group and not just to an item, which I did not know. Thank you for your help

Comment: @SamuelLIOULT There are other methods to scroll without using `CollectionViewSource`. I have updated my answer